# Avoid Rounding Error on Double -> Date conversion

Tags: java, date, time, type-conversion

In my program, I receive strings that define a time stamp in milliseconds. Now I need to convert this to a proper date. The solution I found looks something like this:

```
String aTime = "1365504203.0269";
double t = Double.parseDouble(aTime);

Date date = new Date((long)t*1000);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatDDMMYYYY = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatHHMMssSS = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SS");
String day = new String(dateFormatHHMMssSS.format(date));
String hour = new String(dateFormatDDMMYYYY.format(date));

System.out.println("The Date: "+day);
System.out.println("The Time: "+hour);
```

Unfortunately, this removes the accuracy of milliseconds from the time stamp. (I'm not sure if the time is even that accurate as I can hardly think about it anymore.)

Has it gone lost due to double->long conversion, or has it never been there at all? Any way to workaround this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in this statement:

```
Date date = new Date((long)t*1000);
```

It casts the `double` to a long first, thereby truncating the decimal places, and then multiplies by 1000, which just adds three zeros.  Try this:

```
Date date = new Date((long)(t*1000.0));
```

It uses `double` as the data type for multiplication, which moves the decimal places into the integer part, and then makes the decimal place truncating `long` conversion.

Using `1000.0` instead of `1000` as the constant forces the constant to be of `double` type as well, adding an extra level of certainty that the multiplication will happen with doubles.

Comment: I would drop the usage of `double` and use `BigDecimal` instead for more precision.

Comment: +1, Good find! Just a little edit: Multiplying by 1000 adds three zeros ;)